# How to migrate data from SQL Server database to another over internet

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have two databases in SQL Server 2016 Express, one on the server and the other is local. I want to sync data from the local to the server database every day, one way.

I could not use replication or log shipping because SQL Server edition is Express.
I found the MS Sync framework could help but it is too old.

What is the latest technology for doing that?

Comment: You've named the latest technology to do this in your post, log shipping and replication. The fact that it isn't available in express is because for such tools you need to pay for them. Best advice I can give, therefore, is if you have a small(ish) database is to back it up at at one end and then restore it at the other on a daily basis.

Comment: While you can't use the built-in Log Shipping feature, you are free to copy and apply log backups with a custom script.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Data Sync feature may be a very easy solution for your goal. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data synched not once per day but simultaneously, you could have a look at Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1. https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=23217

I've used it over a custom WCF service, but I think you can use it directly with db connections.